# Order of dot-operator evaluation in Java

Tags: java, evaluation

Inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578210), I started wondering about the well-definedness of the following Java code:

```
public class Test {
    List<Object> foo;

    Object bar() {
        foo = new ArrayList<Object>():
        return(/* Anything */);
    }

    void frob() {
        foo.add(bar());
    }
}
```

In this case, does the Java specification specify a strict order of evaluation for the dot operator in `frob`? Is left-to-right evaluation guaranteed such that the `add` method is always executed on the list that was there before `bar` replaces the field with a new list, or can there legally be compilers that let `bar` execute before the `foo` field is fetched in `frob`, thus executing the `add` method on the new list?

I suspect that left-to-right evaluation is guaranteed, but is there wording in the specification to this effect?

Comment: C and C++ alow somthings to be implementation defined or not well defined so implementations can use the most efficient for their environment.  They sacrifice portability for performance. Java has the opposite design choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is part of [Run-time Evaluation of Method Invocation - Compute Target Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1)

> If the form is `Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier` involved, then:
>
> - If the invocation mode is static, then there is no target reference. The Primary expression is evaluated, but the result is then
>     discarded.
> - Otherwise, **the `Primary` expression is evaluated and the result is used as the target reference.**

Then comes the [evaluation of method arguments.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2)